# Change selected dropdown by ID

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've seen that you can change the selected dropdown item by value but I'd like to do it by the option ID because the values are created dynamically. I am creating a questionnaire with a dropdown menu, the section with questions, and a previous/next button. The values of the dropdown are dynamically created in a php array.

The way I have it set up is similar to this:

```
<select id="myDropdown">
    <option id="1" value="dynamicallycreated1"></option>
    <option id="2" value="dynamicallycreated2"></option>
    <option id="3" value="dynamicallycreated3"></option>
</select>
```

The select is created through php with the index of the array acting as the ID. There are previous/next buttons on the page to move back/forward from section to section. I want the dropdown to change to the appropriate item when the user clicks the next or previous button. I can easily grab the index through my current javascript so how can I change the dropdown using this index as the ID? Thanks!

Comment: Obviously, don't use 1,2,3 for your IDs. This is not valid.

Comment: As stated, an `id` starting with a number is invalid HTML.   But why even bother creating `id`'s for this?  You can just access the `option` items through their `index` (0, 1, 2...) using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks guys, forgot that id's starting with numbers were not valid. Got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Lee Taylor that you should not use 1,2,3 as Id field. You can instead use these values in `value` attribute of a dropdown like

and use jquery to select the element with value = 1 like

```
$('#myDropdown').val(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, just set the `selected` property to `true`:

```
var opt = document.getElementById("1");
opt.selected = true;
```

Tested and works with Firefox.

With jQuery, it would be:

```
$("#1").prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: @azizpunjani could you help me with it?  I have not much jQuery experience.

Comment: `$("#1").prop('selected', true )`

Comment: Great... except for one thing... an `id` starting with a number is invalid HTML, so it's likely not going to work very reliably anyway.

Comment: I found that the array-version works as well, but this looks a little better. I agree on the `id` thing, but that's easily fixed with a prefix.

Comment: Leading numeric id's are valid in html5.

Comment: @azizpunjani, Yes, I forgot about that.  When something is only valid in HTML5 but invalid elsewhere, that detail should be mentioned in the answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about creating any special `id`'s for your `option` items or changing the values.  Just use jQuery to grab the `index`.  (Note that the index starts at `0` so just add `1` to this result if needed.)

```
$('#myDropdown').find('option:selected').index();
```

HTML:

```
<select id="myDropdown">
    <option value="dynamicallycreated1">option one</option>
    <option value="dynamicallycreated2">option two</option>
    <option value="dynamicallycreated3">option three</option>
</select>
```